# Binomial random number generation

Tags: c++, math, random, distribution

I'm struggling to get a random number generator in C++.

- The generator should only return integers between `0` and `n`.
- The probability of returning low numbers should be higher than the probability of high numbers.

Example distribution:

```
1:  ************************
2:  ******************
3:  **************
4:  ************
5:  ********
6:  *****
7:  ****
8:  ***
9:  **
10: *
```

The distribution type doesn't matter in my case. What I have tried is to use a binomial distribution with the values `[0..2*n]`. Afterwards I convert the resulting random numbers into `[0..n]` to get the peak at zero.

```
size_t n = 20;
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::binomial_distribution<int> distribution(n*2, 0.5f);
int number = fabs(distribution(generator)-n);
```

Resulting numbers:

```
0: *************************
1: ***********************************************
2: *****************************************
3: ********************************
4: **********************
5: **************
6: ********
7: ****
8: **
9:
10-20: none. The numbers are very rare.
```

My question: How do you correctly implement such an algorithm? How can I increase the probability of higher values so that the distribution stays the same regardless of the used `n`?

Comment: You could generate random numbers between 0 and n/2 for a certain number of calls to your generation function, then switch back to generating from 0 to n; switching back and forth should give you a higher count of lower values. You can generalize this.

Comment: @user2296177 That's an interesting idea. But the quality of the randomness wouldn't be good enough

Comment: Have you tried `std::geometric_distribution`?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)

```
P(x) = lambda * Exp(-lambda * x)
```

with appropriate parameter lambda that influences on decay speed.

If there is no ready-to-use exponential distribution in your math library (std::exponential_distribution?), just use [inverse transform sampling (Smirnov's) method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).

Delphi example

```
 for i := 0 to 1000000 do begin
    V := Trunc(-ln(Random()) / lambda); 
    //Random function gives random value uniformly distributed on [0,1) 
    if V <= N then begin
      Inc(H[V]); //histogram entry
    end;
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following workaround:

```
do {
        number = (rand() % n) - (rand() % n);
} while(number < 0 || number > n);
```

This gives a correct distribution but is very slow since it needs about 0.9 retries per number.

Comment: Why not `int a = rand() % n, b = rand() % n; number = a >= b? a - b : b - a;`?